# How to learn about designing highly transactional systems?

Tags: database-design, transactions, distributed, high-availability, distributed-transactions

I have been mostly working on data analysis, BI tools, etc. in my career. Most of the applications I work on are majorly read-only applications. Although I have also worked on simple CRUD applications but nothing extraordinarily transactional.
As a software engineer, I feel there is a void in my learning if I don't know how to design highly transactional systems and databases, like how Amazon, airline systems, etc. work.
I would like to ask the community here to suggest some resources, books or simple projects on this subject. Something that can take hands-on approach whilst teaching about the necessary theory. I know this is a subjective matter but I can mark the most useful answer green.
Looking forward to your suggestions and thanking in anticipation.

Comment: Well, unfortunately such questions are off-topic here.

Comment: I understand that but nonetheless this could be an important question

Comment: Of course it's important, if not for me, but for you. But as you say it's subjective and looking for off-site resources. Both are reasons to vote to close.

Comment: Kumar - I think this is an important and valuable questions, and I am going to try to answer it as completely as possible.

Comment: Just waiting for some more answers to follow!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am going to organize the answer in four broad categories, namely

1. theoretical and academic background,
2. popular sources,
3. software and tools, and
4. exercises.

### Books and Papers

This are the foundations of the field - how to go from 0 to quite a decent, expertly level, but mostly theoretically.

#### Intro Level

[Transaction Processing: Concepts and Techniques (The Morgan Kaufmann Series in Data Management Systems)](http://amzn.to/1JO9brY) by Jim Gray

Silberschatz book ([Database System Concepts](http://codex.cs.yale.edu/avi/db-book/)) in the later chapters covers internal workings of the advanced transactional systems, has some resources, etc.

#### Database Specific

[H-store paper](http://hstore.cs.brown.edu/papers/hstore-endofera.pdf) - describes benefits of in-memory design for high transactional loads. H-store work has inspired development of VoltDB.

[Calvin paper](http://cs-www.cs.yale.edu/homes/dna/papers/calvin-sigmod12.pdf) - Fast Distributed Transactions
for Partitioned Database Systems. Gives a very good background, related work, and an insight into the state of the art.

[Architecture of a Database System](http://amzn.to/1RUNj6f) by Hellerstein, Stonebraker and Hamilton
covers many aspects.

#### Limitations and Boundaries

[Great paper](http://www.bailis.org/papers/hat-vldb2014.pdf) on virtues and limitations of highly available transactions.

[CAP Theorem paper](http://www.realtechsupport.org/UB/NP/Numeracy_CAP%2B12Years_2012.pdf) - On the design tradeoffs of consistency, availability and partitioning for large scale systems. **Very important.**

[Parallel Processing and Parallel Databases](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A58617_01/server.804/a58238/ch1_unde.htm)

### Popular and Current Sources

#### Blogs

[High Scalability](http://highscalability.com) is a perfect blog for what you are looking for.
Here is, for example, a [great entry on the evolution of Amazon's architecture](http://highscalability.com/amazon-architecture).Very close to what you've been looking for.

[Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/Engineering), [LinkedIn](https://engineering.linkedin.com/), and [Twitter](https://engineering.twitter.com/) engineering blogs are great resources. I would also check [Google Research](http://research.google.com/pubs/DistributedSystemsandParallelComputing.html) site and their Google+. Netflix is not bad either.

#### Conferences

[VLDB](http://www.vldb.org/conference.html) and SIGMOD conferences (inluding SIGMOD [blog](http://wp.sigmod.org/)) are where most of the most advanced data systems are presented by the researchers/academia, and the corporations.

[HPTS](http://www.hpts.ws/) is an interesting conference/workshop with the good agenda and publications.

I would even check [USENIX series](https://www.usenix.org/conferences) for cutting edge, systems stuff.

### Case Study Architectures

**[VoltDB](https://voltdb.com/products/featuresbenefits/reasons-behind-voltdb-architecture)** is an ultra-transaction, in-memory database, designed by Mike Stonebraker, ACM fellow, and "father" of the most modern database concepts.

IBM **mainframe** still has a very prominent place in the world of high volume transactional 
processing. At the time of the writing of this answer, they are [touting](http://www.wired.com/2015/01/z13-mainframe/) their Z13 system for [extreme, encrypted transaction processing volumes](http://www.americanbanker.com/news/bank-technology/why-citi-is-buying-ibms-new-mainframe-for-mobile-transactions-1072161-1.html).

If you are interested in doing transactions the "Big Data" style, there are lots of choices, but HBase is probably the most interesting one.
Here are some suggested reading sources for HBase:
Yahoo's [Omid](http://yahoohadoop.tumblr.com/post/129089878751/introducing-omid-transaction-processing-for) built on HBase
[Transactions over HBase](http://www.slideshare.net/alexbaranau/transactions-over-hbase)

Another interesting architecture is **[Twitter, now Apache Storm](http://storm.apache.org/talksAndVideos.html).** 
and [Apache Kafka](http://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/developing.realtime.data_.pipelines.with_.apache.kafka_.pdf) for streaming and real-time processing.

### Benchmarks and Exercises

If you want to try few things out, look at the [TPC](http://www.tpc.org/) family of benchmarks. There are transactional, ETL, BI, and decision support/mixed load analytic benchmarks.
These are relational-oriented.

You can take these benchmarks and practice them against the open source SMP (e.g. postgres, MySQL) and MPP databases such as Greenplum (a [link](http://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/4320/admin_guide/query.html) to a great and comprehensive documentation on querying, performance, some sample setups, and [how MPP databases process queries](http://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/4320/admin_guide/parallel_proc.html)).

I recommended [these](http://blog.cask.co/2015/05/scalable-distributed-transactional-queues/) practical scenarios and architectures for HBase-oriented transactional systems.

For state-of-the-art message and actor oriented transactional systems, you will probably need to buy a book or two.
   For Akka (which serves as an internal to Spark) you could probably use [Akka in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/akka-in-action) and go through the exercises at the end of each chapter.
There are also some exercises from the training sessions [here](https://github.com/RayRoestenburg/scala-io-exercise-1).

For stream processing, here are some good exercises with Apache Kafka ([parts 1](http://www.confluent.io/blog/stream-data-platform-1/) and http://www.confluent.io/blog/stream-data-platform-2/). Cloudera has a good "getting started" [guide](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/09/apache-kafka-for-beginners/).

To practice message-oriented state-of-the-art systems, I would suggest [Getting Started with Storm](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/getting-started-with/9781449324025/), and perhaps going through these [exercises](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/getting-started-with/9781449324025/ch08.html). There are number of real-topologies featured.

For good, old JMS, you can use this [online reference](https://tarilabs.wordpress.com/2012/12/30/welcome-to-my-rpi-simple-javaee-exercise-with-webservice-and-jms/) for practice, or
go more sophisticated with these [Active MQ exercises](http://www.infoq.com/resource/articles/snyder-activemq-in-action/en/resources/ActiveMQinActionCH07.pdf).

If you want to torture yourself with the mainframe, try this [emulator](http://www.hercules-390.org/).
It emulates IBM's OS/370-390.

Comment: This is a good answer, Edmond. Thanks for your response. It has very good use cases and literature. However, I'd still ask - what do you think is a good way to 'exercise' this?

Comment: Kumar - do you mean as pure practice exercise or a real life case study replicas?

Comment: yeah, whichever possible. If both, then better.

Comment: Kumar - I added references to some truly excellent sources that cover the whole field - MPPs, HBase (Hadoop's transactional, fast R/W system), message oriented middleware, actors middleware, streaming and even mainframe. Hope this helps you and any others interested in the topic.